# Query Issue Database SQL #1066

Tags: mysql, sql

Query Issue

```
SELECT B.branchId, B.city, S.staffId, firstname, surname, boatId
FROM Branch B, Staff S, BoatsForRent B
WHERE B.branchId = S.branchId AND S.staffId = B.staffId
ORDER BY B.branchId, S.staffId, boatId ;
```

I'm using three tables:-
-BoatsForRent
-Staff
-Branch

I keep getting error:

## 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'B'

I think it's because i have two tables that begin with B, but i'm not sure

Thanks for any help

Comment: its because of two aliased named 'B'

Answer (score 0):

You've got two tables ALIASED to B - Branch and BoatsForRent.  You'll need to give them a unique alias.

Answer (score 0):

When you write Branch B, you are choosing the alias B for the table Branch. Same for BoatsForRent B. Just put BoatsForRent BFR and it will work okay

Answer (score 0):

yes it´s because you created 2 alias with the same name:

```
FROM Branch **B**, Staff S, BoatsForRent **B**
```

change it to:

```
FROM Branch Br, Staff S, BoatsForRent Bo
```

or so.
Also you must change all `B` to the respective alias in the rest of the query

Answer (score 0):

you have to use unique table alias.you can not use same alias.

```
SELECT B.branchId, B.city, S.staffId, firstname, surname, boatId
FROM Branch B, Staff S, BoatsForRent BR
WHERE B.branchId = S.branchId AND S.staffId = BR.staffId
ORDER BY B.branchId, S.staffId, boatId ;
```